# Express async parallel callback function Usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I’m following the local library website project on MDN as in the link below. I came across async parallel but not sure what is one: and two: in the below async.parrallel code. Are these function names or variables?

[local library project link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Displaying_data/Home_page)

[image]

Similarly in the library controller we have book_count: , book_instance_count:, book_instance_available_count:. Is this a way to define a variable or function name?

Trying to understand the syntax and usage please.

```js
var Book = require('../models/book');
var Author = require('../models/author');
var Genre = require('../models/genre');
var BookInstance = require('../models/bookinstance');

var async = require('async');

exports.index = function(req, res) {   
    
    async.parallel({
        book_count: function(callback) {
            Book.countDocuments({}, callback); // Pass an empty object as match condition to find all documents of this collection
        },
        book_instance_count: function(callback) {
            BookInstance.countDocuments({}, callback);
        },
        book_instance_available_count: function(callback) {
            BookInstance.countDocuments({status:'Available'}, callback);
        },
        author_count: function(callback) {
            Author.countDocuments({}, callback);
        },
        genre_count: function(callback) {
            Genre.countDocuments({}, callback);
        }
    }, function(err, results) {
        res.render('index', { title: 'Local Library Home', error: err, data: results });
    });
};
```

Comment: `// results is now equals to: {one: 1, two: 2}` - the results will now have keys you can look them up with.

Comment: agree, but what is one: and two:? are these variables. i.e would the below work.             

const one = function(callback) {
}

Comment: They are arbitrary labels you assign here. You can call them `horse` and `battery`, if you wish. The only matter for your code when want to fetch specific value in the callback after all of these finish.

Comment: sure. So the labels usage is part of async library or a standard javascript syntax? sorry new to javascript. The only place i have come across key:value is when creating a new object in javacript.

Comment: This *is* an object. You pass an object of the form `{one: someFunction, two: otherFunction}` and get back another object `{one: resultOfsomeFunction, two: resultOfotherFunction}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered by VlaZ in comments above

> They are arbitrary labels you assign here. You can call them `horse` and `battery`, if you wish. The only matter for your code when want to fetch specific value in the callback after all of these finish.
> This *is* an object. You pass an object of the form `{one: someFunction, two: otherFunction}` and get back another object `{one: resultOfsomeFunction, two: resultOfotherFunction}`